# Evict all element in EhCache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I am using EhCache with spring and need to expose an endpoint that will evict all element in given EhCache. But I am not able to find any method that evict all element. It is trivial and might be discussed already but I could not find any resource on internet. Please provide pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you using Spring Cache ? then
set true to allEntries property

```
@Cacheable("myCache")
public String getCache() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
    }
    return "aaa";
}

@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "myCache", allEntries = true)
public void evictAll() {
}
```

or if you want to delete all caches that you defined

```
@Autowired
CacheManager cacheManager;

public void evictAll() {
    cacheManager.getCacheNames()
            .stream()
            .forEach(n -> cacheManager.getCache(n).clear());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using sprig Cache But Can we do this pragmatically?

Comment: I amended a my answer. you should call evictAll when you wanna evict all caches

Comment: Thanks for your response. But problem I see here is that I would need to define evictAll method for all caches if I want to do it separately. Is it not possible to do this dynamically? Something like:

evictAllInCache(String cacheName) {
Cache cache = cacheManaget.getCache(cacheName);
cache.evictAll(); //Something like this
}

Comment: I amended my answer again.
unfortunately cache manager doesn't  provide something like evict all 
but you can achieve that with lamda and stream API

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed this clear() method in Cache and that is what I was looking for.